# How can I combine fields in a .csv based off of a shared value in powershell?

Tags: csv, powershell

I have two files in identical formats, one containing destination IP addresses and URLs, and one that contains only the destination IP addresses. I am attempting to write a powershell script to add the URL field from the first file to the second file for that row if the destination IP addresses are equal. Here is an example of the two files:

File Containing URLs:

```
Date;Time;Source;Destination;Port;User;URL
3/7/2016;0:00:07;168.254.25.6;10.0.1.27;80;jsmith;abcnet
```

File to add URLs to:

```
Date;Time;Source;Destination;Port;User;URL
3/7/2016;0:00:09;168.254.25.6;10.0.1.27;80;;
```

Whenever I run the code below, it appears to be caught in an infinite loop because it does not run to completion, but it throws no errors. My data set is thousands of lines long, but it works when I test it with a sample set that is only a few lines long.

```
$noURLs = Import-Csv C:\Path\to\noURLs.csv
$containsURLs = Import-Csv C:\Path\to\containsURLs.csv | Select-Object Destination, URL
$outputFile = "C:\Path\to\output.csv"

if(Test-Path $outputFile){
    Remove-Item $outputFile
}

foreach($line in $noURLs){
    $cpDest = $line.Destination
    $destURL = $containsURLs | Where-Object {$_.Destination -eq $cpDest} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty URL | Select-Object -Unique


    if($destURL -ne $null){
        if( $destURL.Count -gt 1) {
            $destURL = $destURL -join ';'
        }
    }
    $line.URL = $destURL
}

$noURLs | Export-Csv $outputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add a -unique switch to my select object, so for every one record in the first csv, it was looping through every single line of the second csv. Fixed code looks like this:

$noURLs = Import-Csv C:\Path\to\noURLs.csv
$containsURLs = Import-Csv C:\Path\to\containsURLs.csv | Select-Object -Unique Destination, URL
$outputFile = "C:\Path\to\output.csv"

if(Test-Path $outputFile){
    Remove-Item $outputFile
}

foreach($line in $noURLs){
    $cpDest = $line.Destination
    $destURL = $containsURLs | Where-Object {$_.Destination -eq $cpDest} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty URL | Select-Object -Unique

```
if($destURL -ne $null){
    if( $destURL.Count -gt 1) {
        $destURL = $destURL -join ';'
    }
}
$line.URL = $destURL
```

}

$noURLs | Export-Csv $outputFile -NoTypeInformation